# How to implement a LSTM based classifier to classify speech files using Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, softmax, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a LSTM based classifier to recognize speech. I have a dataset of speech samples which contain spoken utterences of numbers from 0 to 9. Each file contains only one number. I have extracted 13 mfcc and each file contain 99 frames. Therefore I have (99 * 13) shaped matrices for each sound file.

```
x_train => (100, 99, 13) => [[frame1 frame2 .... frame99],[frame1 frame2 .... frame99]]
y_train => (100,) => [0 0 0 0 ....... 9 9 9 9]
```

Following the examples [mnist_irnn of keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_irnn.py) I have implemented my network as follows. (I just set the hidden units to 13 because I wanted to make it fast)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

from keras.optimizers import SGD
np.random.seed(1337)
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from SpeechResearch import loadData

'exception_verbosity = high'
batch_size = 5
hidden_units = 13
nb_classes = 10
print('Loading data...')
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = loadData.load_mfcc(10, 2)

print(len(X_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(X_test), 'test sequences')
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('X_test shape:', X_test.shape)
print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
print('y_test shape:', y_test.shape)
print(y_test)
print('Build model...')

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=hidden_units, init='uniform', inner_init='uniform',
               forget_bias_init='one', activation='tanh', inner_activation='sigmoid', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))

model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

print("Train...")
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=3, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), show_accuracy=True)
score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            show_accuracy=True)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

I have tried my best to set the values according to the example. But when I run the code I am getting following error. (I will include print statements as well because that help to get an idea about dimensions about each matrix)

```
Using Theano backend.
Loading data...
100 train sequences
20 test sequences
X_train shape: (100, 99, 13)
X_test shape: (20, 99, 13)
y_train shape: (100,)
y_test shape: (20,)
[0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9]
Build model...
Train...
Train on 100 samples, validate on 20 samples
Epoch 1/3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/udani/PycharmProjects/testResearch/SpeechResearch/lstmNetwork.py", line 58, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=3, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), show_accuracy=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 581, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle, metrics=metrics)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 239, in _fit
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 365, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)
  File "/home/udani/Documents/ResearchSW/Theano/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 871, in __call__
    storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
  File "/home/udani/Documents/ResearchSW/Theano/theano/gof/link.py", line 314, in raise_with_op
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
  File "/home/udani/Documents/ResearchSW/Theano/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 859, in __call__
    outputs = self.fn()
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 1, input[1].shape[1] = 10)
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * log(i1))}}(<TensorType(float32, matrix)>, Elemwise{Clip}[(0, 0)].0)
Toposort index: 215
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(5, 1), (5, 10)]
Inputs strides: [(4, 4), (40, 4)]
Inputs values: [array([[ 0.],
       [ 9.],
       [ 8.],
       [ 8.],
       [ 6.]], dtype=float32), 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Sum{axis=[1], acc_dtype=float64}(Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * log(i1))}}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am unable to figure out why am I getting this exception. I am really thankful to anyone who can help me to solve this. I am totally new to these network modeling and Keras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see there are some mistakes in your code.

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=3, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), show_accuracy=True)
score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            show_accuracy=True)
```

In above code you should change following parts,
`y_train to Y_train` and `y_test to Y_test`

Then your code will work fine! good luck!

Comment: Ya it worked. I have been using y_train and y_test instead of using the new variable. My mistake.... :)